# Network-wide tour page says "may be closed" - maybe replace it with "may be put on hold"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tour

The network-wide tour page (including Stack Overflow and every other SE site I checked, but not Meta.SE) says the following:

> Questions that need improvement may be **closed** until someone fixes them.

I think it would be more consistent with the site itself to say something like the following:

> Questions that need improvement may be put **on hold** until someone fixes them.

Comment: While we're at it *until someone fixes them.* ... shouldn't that *someone* be the "asker"?